# set image as a wallpaper in android dynamically without any zoom

Tags: android, image, zooming, wallpaper

I'm new to android programming and i'm creating an app that it has a button and an ImageView. there's only one ImageView and the image inside it changes dynamically according to user choice. Now what i want to do is that when the user tap the button , the image become the phone's wallpaper. here are two codes that i tried but when it becomes the wallpaper , it's very big that you only see a small part as a wallpaper.first i tried this one :

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable",  getPackageName());
                WallpaperManager wpm =  WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    wpm.setResource(resID);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Wallpaper successfully changed",         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
      }
        });
```

and the second one that I've tried and replaced is :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Wallpaper successfully changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

I also add these two permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" /
>
```

I don't know where is the problem. Plz help

Comment: I have the same problem. Will post as soon as I solve it.